# sqlalchemy NoSuchTableError when table exists in database

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am using PostgreSQL+Psycopg2, SQLAlchemy. I've already created my database "new_db" using pgAdminIII tool and a new schema in it as "new_db_schema". Under this schema I've all the tables I need. My code looks like this.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Boolean

engine_text = 'postgresql+psycopg2://root:12345@localhost:5432/db_name'
database_engine = create_engine(engine_text, echo = True)

Base = declarative_base(database_engine)

class Some_table(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table' # This table exist in database.
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

    col1 = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    col2 = Column(Boolean)

    def __init__(self, col1_name, col2_name):
        self.col1 = col1_name
        self.col2 = col2_name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Some_table('blah', 'blah')
```

Now when i try to run the following code, I get `sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: some_table`.

Since I already have the database setup with all the tables, I would like to autoload while creating classes. Am I missing something here? I need to write such classes for all the tables present in the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You created your schema in `new_db_schema` and are calling it to `...5432/db_name`. Shouldn't it be the same db?

Comment: @fedorqui: I've created a DB "new_db" and created a new schema under it "new_db_schema" using pgAdmin tool. When I change the database name for create_engine to point to the schema, it throws error "database "new_db_schema" does not exist". There was a "public" schema already present under schema section which I deleted and created a new one instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- Use schema-qualified table names: `__tablename__ = 'new_db_schema.some_table'`. You have to use them everywhere: in string arguments to `ForeignKey` etc.
- Alter `SEARCH_PATH` in the database: `SET search_path TO new_db_schema;`. This SQL command has session scope, so you have to issue it at the start of every connection using SQLAlchemy event system.

Like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def init_search_path(connection, conn_record):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute('SET search_path TO new_db_schema;')
    finally:
        cursor.close()

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://...')
event.listen(engine, 'connect', init_search_path)
```

Comment: I am getting this error after changing: `AttributeError: 'psycopg2._psycopg.connection' object has no attribute 'execute'`

Comment: I got the solution. created a session object and then fired this `sess.execute("SET search_path TO new_db_schema")`. It worked! Thank you rkhayrov and fedorqui.

Comment: I've update the answer to fix error (I forgot that `connection.execute` is not mandated by DB-API spec). Using events is more reliable because SQLAlchemy can use connection pooling and statement passed to `session.execute` may not affect all connections.